# VR inspection pink screen

Tags: vr

Hey guys, I'm trying to get VR inspection working but no success so far. Tried oculus and windows OpenXR ...error, then tried steamVR and I advanced to the pink screen problem that is supposed to be solved (ticked closed), I can see the vr camera and controls moving but no video output on my headset. Could it be a case of multi gpu problem? Any light on this will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Meta Quest 2 256GB
Motherboard: Pro WS X570-ACE
CPU : AMD ryzen 7 3700X
GPU 1: rtx3060 gygabyte
GPU 2: rtx3090 gygabyte
GPU 3: rtx3090 evga

Running on Windows 11Pro 21H2 build 22000.2295
Also tried on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS